# Get the time from a Cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to get the Time from the text in an Excel cell. The Text contains the Ticket number, Ticket title, the Time log and the Percentage. All of them are in a single cell. See example below:

`12345678: The bottom part is incorrect 0:15h 0%`

I need to get the `0:15`. I tried to use the LEFT and RIGHT function combination but it will only work if the percentage from the last sentence is only 1 digit. The percentage varies from 0% - 100%. The length of the ticket title varies as well.

Comment: Do you have only this value in cell or many Rows having String with Time Value,, because any specific Formula may pull the time with this but what about others like when Time is `PNR 123456789 Find Time At End 19:20 Hrs.`, so better edit the post & add some sample data!!

Answer (score 2):

I use free [reg-ex replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php)* which adds regular expression functionality to Excel, with that you can use this formula:

`=RegExFind(A2,"\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}")`

[image]

`*` *I'm not affiliated with that add-in*

Answer (score 1):

Máté Juhász's answer is certainly the simplest.  However, if you don't want to get the add-on and aren't familiar with regex (and don't want to learn), there is a more convoluted way to get the result using built-in functions.  It can be simplified a bit if you use helper columns to avoid repetition.  I'll use that to explain how it works.

[image]

All of the "words" are separated with spaces.  The ticket title can have varying numbers of words.  The last element, the percentage, is after the last space, and the time is after the next to last space.  Column B calculates the count of spaces with this formula:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

This formula works by eliminating all of the spaces and then calculating how many characters that shortened the string.  In the example, there are 7 spaces.

Column C peels off the end of the string starting with the time.  The formula is:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),B1-1))+1,LEN(A1))
```

This works by substituting an arbitrary target character that doesn't occur in the data (CHAR(1) in this case), for the space before the time (i.e., next to last space), using the SUBSTITUTE feature that lets you specify a specific instance to replace.  FIND then locates the position of that character, and MID extracts the rest of the string starting at the next position.

The result in Column D extracts the time with this formula:

```
=LEFT(C1,FIND("h",C1)-1)
```

It works by finding the "h" and extracting everything that comes before it.

You can do this in a single formula without using helper columns.  If you replace helper cell references with the helper cell formulas, that formula would look like this:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1))+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("h",MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1))+1,LEN(A1)))-1)
```

Note that all this assumes clean data with no trailing spaces.  If trailing spaces are a possibility, wrap all references to A1 with TRIM() or trim A1 in a helper column and refer to that to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(E10);"h ";REPT(" ";99));99));5))
```

Comment: This relies on the specific content of the example.  It won't give the right result with an example where the ticket title contains a word that ends in `h`, like "both", or where the time log has 2-digit hours.

Comment: @fixer1234 You are correct.